# Why am I getting this SIGSEGV signal in my catch2 test?

Tags: c++, templates, segmentation-fault, catch2

I am currently learning c++ and as an exercise, I've been trying to implement a linked list data structure. I am writing tests for it in Catch2 and I keep getting a SIGSEGV signal and I can't figure out why.

Here is my linked list header file:

```cpp
#pragma once

namespace datastructures{
  template <typename T>
  class LinkedList{
    private:
      class Node
      {
        private:
          T m_data;
          Node *m_next;
        public:
          Node(T data);

          ~Node();

          Node* get_next();

          void set_next(T data);

          void set_next(Node* next);

          T get_data();

          void set_data(T data);
      };

      Node *m_head;
      int m_size;

    public:

      /**
       * @brief Construct a new Linked List object
       * 
       */
      LinkedList();

      LinkedList(const LinkedList &other);

      LinkedList & operator=(const LinkedList &other);

      /**
       * @brief Destroy the Linked List object
       * 
       */
      ~LinkedList();

      /**
       * @brief get the size of the list
       * 
       * @return int 
       */
      int size();

      /**
       * @brief Returns true if the list is empty
       * 
       * @return true 
       * @return false 
       */
      bool is_empty();

      /**
       * @brief Get the first value in the list
       * 
       * @return T 
       */
      T first();

      /**
       * @brief get the value from the given index in the list
       * 
       * @param index 
       * @return T 
       */
      T get(int index);

      /**
       * @brief remove the value from the given index from the list
       * 
       * @param index 
       * @return T the removed value
       */
      T remove(int index);

      /**
       * @brief Sets the value at the given index to the given value
       * 
       * @param index 
       * @param val
       */
      void set(int index, T val);

      /**
       * @brief Inserts the given value at the given index in the list
       * 
       * @param index 
       * @param val 
       */
      void insert(int index, T val);

      /**
       * @brief Appends the given value to the end of the list
       * 
       * @param val 
       */
      void append(T val);
  };
}

#include "templates/linked_list.tcc"
```

Here is my linked list implementation file:

```cpp
#include <datastructures/linked_list.hpp>

using namespace datastructures;

#pragma region Node Implementation

template <typename T>
LinkedList<T>::Node::Node(T data){
  m_data = data;
  m_next = NULL;
}

template <typename T>
LinkedList<T>::Node::~Node(){
  //Do nothing. Deletion of member m_next is out of this classes scope.
}

template <typename T>
typename LinkedList<T>::Node* LinkedList<T>::Node::get_next(){
  return m_next;
}

template <typename T>
void LinkedList<T>::Node::set_next(T data){
  LinkedList<T>::Node* tmp = new LinkedList<T>::Node(data);

  //Don't delete previous next object. That is handled by the linked list class

  m_next = tmp;
}

template <typename T>
void LinkedList<T>::Node::set_next(LinkedList<T>::Node* next){

  //Don't delete previous next object. That is handled by the linked list class

  m_next = next;
}

template <typename T>
T LinkedList<T>::Node::get_data(){
  return m_data;
}

template <typename T>
void LinkedList<T>::Node::set_data(T data){
  m_data = data;
}

#pragma endregion

#pragma region Linked List Implementation

template <typename T>
LinkedList<T>::LinkedList(){
  m_size = 0;
  m_head = NULL;
}

template <typename T>
LinkedList<T>::~LinkedList(){
  typename LinkedList<T>::Node* currentNode = m_head;

  while (currentNode != NULL)
  {
    typename LinkedList<T>::Node* tmp = currentNode->get_next();

    delete currentNode;

    currentNode = tmp;
  }

}

template <typename T>
int LinkedList<T>::size(){
  return m_size;
}

template <typename T>
bool LinkedList<T>::is_empty(){
  return m_size == 0;
}

template <typename T>
T LinkedList<T>::first(){
  if (m_head == NULL)
  {
    throw "List is empty";
  }

  return m_head->get_data();

}

template <typename T>
T LinkedList<T>::get(int index){
  if (index >= m_size || index < 0)
  {
      throw "Index out of bounds";
  }

  typename LinkedList<T>::Node* currentNode = m_head;
  int currentIndex = 0;

  while (currentIndex < index)
  {
    currentNode = currentNode->get_next();
    currentIndex++;
  }

  return currentNode->get_data();
}


template <typename T>
T LinkedList<T>::remove(int index){
  if (index >= m_size || index < 0)
  {
      throw "Index out of bounds";
  }


  typename LinkedList<T>::Node *prevNode = NULL;
  typename LinkedList<T>::Node *currentNode = m_head;
  int currentIndex = 0;

  while (currentIndex < index)
  {

    prevNode = currentNode;
    currentNode = currentNode->get_next();
    currentIndex++;
  }

  T removed_val;

  // Special case if deleting the first element
  if (prevNode == NULL){
    m_head = currentNode->get_next();
    removed_val = currentNode->get_data();
    delete currentNode;
  }
  else{
    prevNode->set_next(currentNode->get_next());
    removed_val = currentNode->get_data();
    delete currentNode;
  }

  m_size--;

  return removed_val;
}


template <typename T>
void LinkedList<T>::set(int index, T val){
  if (index >= m_size || index < 0)
  {
      throw "Index out of bounds";
  }

  typename LinkedList<T>::Node* currentNode = m_head;
  int currentIndex = 0;

  while (currentIndex < index)
  {
    currentNode = currentNode->get_next();
    currentIndex++;
  }

  currentNode->set_data(val);
}


template <typename T>
void LinkedList<T>::insert(int index, T val){

  if (index >= m_size || index < 0)
  {
      throw "Index out of bounds";
  }

  typename LinkedList<T>::Node* prevNode = NULL;
  typename LinkedList<T>::Node* currentNode = m_head;
  typename LinkedList<T>::Node* newNode = new LinkedList<T>::Node(val);
  int currentIndex = 0;

  while (currentIndex < index)
  {
    prevNode = currentNode;
    currentNode = currentNode->get_next();
    currentIndex++;
  }

  // Special case if inserting the first element
  if (prevNode == NULL){
    m_head = newNode;
    newNode->set_next(currentNode);
  }
  // All other cases should be covered by this
  else{
    prevNode->set_next(newNode);
    newNode->set_next(currentNode);
  }

  m_size++;
}

template <typename T>
void LinkedList<T>::append(T val){
  if(m_size == 0 && m_head == NULL){
    m_head = new LinkedList<T>::Node(val);
  }

  typename LinkedList<T>::Node* prevNode = NULL;
  typename LinkedList<T>::Node* currentNode = m_head;
  typename LinkedList<T>::Node* newNode = new LinkedList<T>::Node(val);
  int currentIndex = 0;

  while (currentIndex < m_size)
  {
    prevNode = currentNode;
    currentNode = currentNode->get_next();
    currentIndex++;
  }

  prevNode->set_next(newNode);

  m_size++;
}

#pragma endregion
```

and here are my catch2 tests:

```cpp
#include <catch2/catch.hpp>
#include <datastructures/linked_list.hpp>

#include <iostream>

using namespace datastructures;

TEMPLATE_TEST_CASE("linked_list", "[linked_list][Template]", int){
  SECTION("can be constructed without issue"){
    LinkedList<int> list = LinkedList<int>();

    REQUIRE(list.size() == 0);
  }

  SECTION("Can append values"){
    LinkedList<int> list = LinkedList<int>();

    list.append(1);

    REQUIRE(list.size() == 1);
    REQUIRE(list.get(0) == 1);

    list.append(2);

    REQUIRE(list.size() == 2);
    REQUIRE(list.get(1) == 2);
  }


  SECTION("Can remove values"){
    LinkedList<int> list = LinkedList<int>();

    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
      list.append(i);
    }

    REQUIRE(list.size() == 5);
    REQUIRE(list.get(4) == 4);

    list.remove(4);

    REQUIRE(list.size() == 4);

    list.remove(0);

    REQUIRE(list.size() == 3);
    REQUIRE(list.get(0) == 1);

  }


  SECTION("Can set arbitrary values"){
    LinkedList<int> list = LinkedList<int>();

    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
      list.append(i);
    }

    REQUIRE(list.size() == 5);
    REQUIRE(list.get(4) == 4);

    list.set(0, 9);

    REQUIRE(list.size() == 5);
    REQUIRE(list.get(0) == 9);

    list.set(4, 22);

    REQUIRE(list.size() == 5);
    REQUIRE(list.get(4) == 22);
  }

  SECTION("Can get arbitrary values"){
    LinkedList<int> list = LinkedList<int>();

    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
      list.append(i);
    }

    REQUIRE(list.get(0) == 0);
    REQUIRE(list.get(1) == 1);
    REQUIRE(list.get(2) == 2);
    REQUIRE(list.get(3) == 3);
    REQUIRE(list.get(4) == 4);
  }

  SECTION("Can insert values at arbitrary indices"){
    LinkedList<int> list = LinkedList<int>();

    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
      list.append(i);
    }

    REQUIRE(list.size() == 5);
    REQUIRE(list.get(4) == 4);

    list.insert(3, 99);

    REQUIRE(list.size() == 6);
    REQUIRE(list.get(3) == 99);;
    REQUIRE(list.get(4) == 3);

  }

  SECTION("Accurately tracks the list's size"){
    LinkedList<int> list = LinkedList<int>();

    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
      REQUIRE(list.size() == i);
      list.append(i);
    }

  }

  SECTION("Can tell when the list is empty"){
    LinkedList<int> list = LinkedList<int>();

    REQUIRE(list.is_empty());

    list.append(0);

    REQUIRE_FALSE(list.is_empty());
  }
}
```

The test I am getting the SIGSEGV signal on is `SECTION("can append values")`, however if I remove this test then I get the signal on the next one.

I know that these signals typically come from accessing memory you are not supposed to, however I'm not sure where exactly that might be happening.

(Note that the copy constructor and assignment operator overload are not yet implemented. I don't think that could cause this though, but please correct me if I am wrong)

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Your `remove` function says it returns a `T`, but never does. That's UB.

Comment: Good catch. I changed it and updated my question. It unfortunately did not stop the signal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `append` function is broken. Actually just the first if condition is broken. You need to increment `m_size` and return if appending to an empty list.

Here's a code that doesn't crash (at least on `append` calls).

```
if(m_size == 0 && m_head == NULL)
{
    m_head = new LinkedList<T>::Node(val);
    m_size++;  // increment size
    return;    // and return right away
}
```

If you don't do the return, you end up allocating extra Nodes, and not linking things correctly.

On a side note, this piece of code is weird

```
template <typename T>
LinkedList<T>::Node::~Node(){
  //Do nothing. Deletion of member m_next is out of this classes scope.
}
```

You are writing a linked list class that *allocates* memory, but *deleting* memory is too complicated?

Also, don't use `NULL`, please use `nullptr`.

Comment: That fixed it! What is the difference between using NULL and nullptr?
Also, the reason I added that bit in the destructer is because typically for a class with dynamically allocated memory I know you would want to free up that memory when it is deleted. But for nodes when a node is deleted I don't necessarily want to delete the next one it points to. Is this organization bad practice?

Comment: `NULL` is a 0. That is not really an invalid address. `nullptr` is a type-safe way of signifying that.

Comment: Yeah, you'll leak memory if you don't delete Nodes. A simple of rule of thumb is, one `new` per `append`, and one `delete` per `remove`.